# Cumulative Sum List

Tags: python, numpy, cumsum

I'm trying to create a cumulative list, but my output clearly isn't cumulative. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

l=[]
for i in range (50):
    def nextTime(rateParameter):
        return -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / rateParameter
    a = np.round(nextTime(1/15),0)
    l.append(a)
np.cumsum(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: python 3 I suppose? Why dividing by 1/15 when you can multiply by 15 ? loss of precision and speed.

Comment: I'm trying to use the poisson distribution where lambda = 15. That's the code I was instructed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative sum is not taken *in place*, you have to assign the return value:

```
cum_l = np.cumsum(l)
print(cum_l)
```

You don't need to place that function in the `for` loop. Putting it outside will avoid defining a new function at every iteration and your code will still produce the expected result.

Comment: @ChristopherFlach If the answer solved your problem you may consider accepting it :)

Comment: Thanks again! I'm new here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `numpy` then `numpy` is the way to go, however, if all you need to do is provide a cumulative sum then Python3 comes with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
def nextTime(rateParameter):
    while True:
        yield -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / rateParameter

>>> list(it.accumulate(map(round, it.islice(nextTime(1/15), 50))))
[2, 9, 14, 26, 27, ...]
```